# Things to do in Wailea, Maui when you don't have a car

Tags: activities, hawaii, maui

My boyfriend and I are trying to conserve money while on vacation in Maui and weren't planning on renting a car.  Are there things to do in Wailea that are walking distance (or bus transportation)?

Comment: Things to do besides the obvious of enjoying the beautiful beach, which we will be doing plenty of.  :)

Answer (score 4):

If you enjoy golfing, the Old Blue golf course is a championship course and right in Wailea. Willie K is fun to go see - he's frequently performing at Mulligans, the Blue course restaurant.

The Wailea boardwalk runs along the oceanfront and is a great place for a romantic walk and enjoying the sunset.

If you're thinking of taking a tour of any kind, look for the ones that will pick you up at the place you're staying, not all will but some do.

Have a great stay on Maui!

Answer (score 4):

Those are great points. You can also rent a bike while on Maui or take the Maui Bus. The Maui Bus is inexpensive, I believe it is only $2 per ride, anywhere on the Island, but it is not typically on time. The hotels in Wailea also have great Luau's and often have other activities that you can sign up for as well. Check out the Maui Sailing Canoe as well - that is a fun activity that leaves from the beach of the Grand Wailea I believe. Also, Blue Water Rafting is  a fun boat trip that leaves from Kihei Harbor, so that is easy to get to from Wailea. Of course, you have The Shops of Wailea as well that offer great food and shopping too. Enjoy Maui!

Answer (score 4):

You can rent bicycles or scooters to get around, but also keep in mind that your hotel will offer some kind of shuttle and the Maui bus makes 3 stops in [Wailea](http://www.waileatoday.com) and contrary to what was posted above, they are very timely (from my limited experience). In Wailea you have tennis, golf, water activities, etc., so you don't NEED a car but one is welcomed.